# cannot access to hessian remote service at [http://0.0.0.0:8080/SpringDemo-Server/remoting/NotifierService]

Tags: java, spring

Can someone help me with my problem?

I have following error:

Tests in error:

```
   testCreateNewCustomer(eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.di.testdependencyinjection.BankServiceTest): Cannot connect to Hessian remote service at [http://0.0.0.0:8080/SpringDemo-Server/remoting/NotifierService]; nested exception is com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianConnectionException: HessianProxy cannot connect to 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/SpringDemo-Server/remoting/NotifierService

   testGetAllCustomers(eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.di.testdependencyinjection.BankServiceTest): Cannot connect to Hessian remote service at [http://0.0.0.0:8080/SpringDemo-Server/remoting/NotifierService]; nested exception is com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianConnectionException: HessianProxy cannot connect to 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/SpringDemo-Server/remoting/NotifierService
```

I dont know where can be problem.

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                                                                                               
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-                                             
   aop-3.0.xsd">``



  <import resource="spring-db-config.xml"/>
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
  <bean 
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplateDatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="springJdbcCustomerDao"    
   class="eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.di.testdependencyinjection.dao.impl.JdbcTemplateCustomerDaoImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplateDatasource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="bankService" 
   class="eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.di.testdependencyinjection.service.impl.BankServiceImpl">
    <property name="customerDao" ref="springJdbcCustomerDao"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="notifier" class="eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.commons.springdemocommons.SysOutNotifier" /> 

  <bean  
   class="eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.di.testdependencyinjection.aspect.BankServiceLoggingAspect">
    <property name="notifier" ref="remoteNotifier"/>
  </bean>  

  <bean id="remoteNotifier" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="${url.adress}" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"   
     value="eu.ibacz.swsc.spring.commons.springdemocommons.Notifier"/>
  </bean>


  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>urlconfig.properties</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

urlconfing.properties looks this way:

```
   url.adress=http://0.0.0.0:8080/SpringDemo-Server/remoting/NotifierService
```

I have already started Jetty Server using command prompt.

thx for help